OnTapGesture within a ScrollView are not working because
I'm creating a view that displays a list of objects which all contain a box which is clickable. I'm having issues with only some of the boxes responding to the tap gesture. It is weird, because some of them do and others don't... I saw other previous solutions that seemed similar but none of them worked.
This is what I tried:
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct EventStepView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EventViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var appViewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var event: Event
    
    @State private var isLocked = true // State to hold the lock status
    
    @State private var isSelected = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        ZStack {
            KFImage(URL(string: event.image))
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(height: 70)
                .opacity(0.8)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color("FontColor"), lineWidth: 3)
                )
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(event.name)
                        .font(.custom("Inter-Regular_bold", size: 18))
                    Text(event.date, style: .date) // Format the date as needed
                        .font(.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 17))
                }
                .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))
                
                Spacer()
                ZStack {
                    if !isLocked {
                        Image(systemName: "lock.fill")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                    } else if event.attendees.contains(viewModel.userId) {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.diamond.fill")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "diamond")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("X")
                    if !isLocked && appViewModel.currentUser!.id == viewModel.userId {
                        viewModel.addAttendeeToEvent(eventId: event.id!, userId: viewModel.userId)
                        isLocked = false
                        isSelected = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        }
        .onAppear {
            isLocked = Date() > event.date
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EventStepView(viewModel: EventViewModel(userId: "testId"), event: Event.defaultEvent)
}


import SwiftUI

struct EventStepsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EventViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.events) {
                        event in
                        
                        VStack(spacing:0 ) {
                            
                            EventStepView(viewModel: viewModel, event: event)
                            
                            if event != viewModel.events.last {
                                    
                                    VStack(spacing:0) {
                                        SemiCircle().rotation(.degrees(180)).frame(width:20)
                                        
                                        Rectangle().frame(width: 6, height:60)
                                        
                                        SemiCircle()
                                .frame(width:20)
                                    }
                                    .foregroundStyle(Color("FontColor"))
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .onAppear {
                        scrollView
                            .scrollTo(viewModel.events.last?.id)
                    }
                    
                }
        }
        .background(Color("Background"), ignoresSafeAreaEdges: .all)
    }
}

#Preview {
    EventStepsView(viewModel: EventViewModel(userId: "testUser"))
}


And the view being accessed is this one
import SwiftUI

struct EventView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EventViewModel
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appViewModel: AppViewModel
    
    var userId: String
    
    init(userId: String) {
        self.userId = userId
        _viewModel = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: EventViewModel(userId: userId))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            EventStepsView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.fetchEvents()
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbarBackground(
                    Color("Background"),
                    for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text("FRESHERS WEEK")
                            .modifier(ViewHeadingStyle())
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    dismiss()
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    EventView(userId:"test")
}


You should try narrowing down your code to an MRE and excluding 3rd parties. It is hard to help when it would take so much effort to recreate your issue.

Solved by:
Solved by adding the modifier .contentShape(Rectangle()) to the KFImage. The issue seemed to be that the images were not being loaded completely or something within the lines, preventing the gesture from being executed.
